# Why is this undecidability proof for $E_{TM}$ valid?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, decidability

I understand what it means to reduce a problem and how this is used to show by contradiction that the theorem is true.

**Question**
What troubles me is the way the proof is formulated. In step 1.2 it is not defined what will happen if it does not accept. Wouldn't this mean that $M_1$ would run indefinitely for words not accepted by $M$? Furthermore, wouldn't this cause S to not be a decider but rather a recogniser?

**Proof**
The proof is by contradiction. Assume that $E_{TM}$ (Empty turing machines) is decidable. Then there is a TM $M_E$ that decides it. We construct a TM S as follows:

S = On input ⟨M,w⟩ where M is a TM and w a string:

1. Construct a TM $M_1$ as follows:
   $M_1$ = On input x:
   1.1 If $x \neq w$, reject.
   1.2 Run M on input w and accept if M does.
2. Run $M_E$ on input ⟨$M_1$⟩.
3. If $M_E$ accepts, reject; if $M_E$ rejects, accept.

Clearly, S decides $A_{TM}$ . That’s a contradiction. So $E_{TM}$ is undecidable.

Comment: Yes, it's a copy of the proof I was provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea for $S$ is to execute $M_E$ on $\langle M\rangle$. If $M_E$ accepts $\langle M\rangle$ then $L(M)=\emptyset$, so $M$ surely doesn't accept $w$. If $M_E$ rejects $\langle M\rangle$ all we know is that $L(M)\neq\emptyset$, i.e. that $M$ indeed does accept *some* string. We don't know if $M$, in particolar, accepts $w$. So the idea is to modify $M$ (into $M_1$) such that $M_1$ immidiately rejects all the strings $x$ that are not $w$, while on $w$ it just works like $M$. In this way either $L(M_1)=\emptyset$ or $L(M_1)=\{w\}$. Since $L(M_1)$ is the set of strings accepted by $M_1$, the fact that $L(M_1)=\emptyset$ tells us that there's no string accepted by $M_1$. But, and this is the *crucial observation* to answer your question, to not accept a string does not mean to reject. In fact a Turing machine running on a string can: accept, reject or run forever. So, the "*negation of accepting a string*" is "*rejecting or running on it forever*". This tells us that:

1. $L(M_1)=\emptyset$ if and only if $M_1$ does not accept any string, which is equivalent to say that $M$ rejects or runs indefinitely on $w$
2. $L(M_1)\neq\emptyset$ if and only if $L(M_1)=\{w\}$, which is equivalent to say that $M$ accepts $w$

At this point let's execute $M_E$ on $\langle M_1\rangle$:
$$M_E(\langle M_1\rangle)=\begin{cases}\text{accept}\:\Longleftrightarrow\:L(M_1)=\emptyset\:\Longleftrightarrow\:M \text{ rejects or runs indefinitely on } w\\\text{reject}\:\Longleftrightarrow\:L(M_1)\neq\emptyset\:\Longleftrightarrow\:M\text{ accepts }w\end{cases}$$
So we can easily define:
$$S(\langle M,w\rangle)=\begin{cases}\text{accept}\:\Longleftrightarrow\:M_E(\langle M_1\rangle)\text{ reject}\\\text{reject}\:\Longleftrightarrow\:M_E(\langle M_1\rangle)\text{ accept}\end{cases}$$

And note that this is, by definition, a decider for $A_{TM}$, because it accepts if and only if $M$ accepts $w$, and it rejects if and only if $M$ *does not accept* (i.e. rejects or runs on the input indefinitely) $w$.

Comment: Your concise walkthrough of the problem made me aware of what I missed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't focus on what is happening in step 1.2, you should think at it just as part of a definition for $M_1$. In fact, the supposition that $M_E$ decides $E_{TM}$ grants that if $M_E(<M_1>)$ accepted it means that $M(w)$ accepted too. Keep in mind that $<M_1> \in E_{TM} \iff M_E(<M_1>) accepts \iff M(w) accepts \iff <M,w> \in A_{TM}$, which is the meaning of the reduction itself: you are deciding wether $<M,w> \in A_{TM}$ by using the decider $E_M$, but you know that $A_{TM}$ is not decidable so that's a contradiction.